# Reduce android app startup time

Tags: android, performance, oncreate

I am developing an app that uses a shared preferences file and it also contains ads. When I open my app for the first time (running from android studio) my main activity's taking 14-16 seconds to load. After caching it takes 2 seconds to load. I realised that I was putting too many operations in my onCreate() method.Then I tried using onResume(), but it is still taking the same time. I would like to know how I could reduce this startup time. My app uses a shared preference file and it contains ads.I also noticed that my app cache is 20MB.
Code is as follows

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    EditText nme_key = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_key);
    EditText cls_key = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.class_key);
    EditText num_key = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number_key);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key),MODE_PRIVATE);
    nme_key.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("name","name"));
    cls_key.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("class","class"));
    num_key.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("number","number"));
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "");
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("").build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

I have 3 questions

1. How to reduce the startup time of my app ( Threads?)
2. How to reduce the cache size of my app
3. How can I improve my app performance

Comment: try to remove the ads and see what happens.

Comment: It took 12 seconds, still a lot isn't it

Comment: It'll depend about the phone too. For the first Startup you can use [SplashScreen](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/). Also has many articles showing how to reduce the size and improve performance.

Comment: Are you using a custom `Application` class?

Comment: @Adley I am using a splash screen and I referred the same link you tagged( better than other implementations BTW)

Comment: you need to identify what is taking so long. It could be the layout, if it is vey very very complicated, it could be your phone if it is from the last decade, it could be the loading of the shared prefs if you really have a lot in there. Things like [TimingLogger](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TimingLogger.html) can help you figure it out.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede no I am not. My main activity extends AppCompatActivity and implements View.OnClickListener

Comment: @VaM999 Way better. So I'm looking for reduce size for my app too. Take a look at [proguard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)

Comment: @njzk2 My shared prefs file has just the 3 key,value pairs I used in the given code.

Comment: Like @njzk2 said, you need to figure out what's taking the time. Comment everything out and add them in one at a time until you see a jump in load time. Then you know that's what's taking the time and you can dig in an see why.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that Ads are the reason that makes my application takes too long to start.

**So, this how I fixed it:**

```
//run in the background
AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
            MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {});
            //Banner Ad
            AdView adView = findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

            //Interstitial Ad
            mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");


            //you have to load the Ads in the foreground
            this.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                adView.loadAd(adRequest);
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

            });
        });
```

**How to show Interstitial Ad:**

```
button.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            //check first, if it is instantiated and loaded
            if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }
        });
```

But be aware that this will make your app start without showing any ads until they load up.
I know I'm very late but I hope this will help people in the feature.